# How can we understand ruby on rails generate call in layman's term?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

Disclaimer : I am a total novice to programming itself , I have done some C++ stuff only . I had an idea and wanted to code the preliminary part of the website myself. Hence , I looked around and decided to jump on to the Ruby on Rails bandwagon. But I am not quite getting the grip of the generate command and how is it being very different from scaffold. Again , please pardon me , I am starting out and thought if anyone over here can guide me to good tutorials or easy way of making it understand . Any answers, small or big are appreciated !

I am following The Intro to RoR ( Berkeley events youtube ) set but it seems outdated , so I have been trying to follow random youtube videos .

Comment: Just wondering if my answer was helpful. Also, "random youtube videos" probably isn't the way to go. In Stack Overflow, if you click the `ruby-on-rails` tag, you will see a folder tab titled "info". Click on that and you'll find more canonical resources. Off the top of my head, I would recommend "Learn RonR by Example" by Michael Hartl, Ruby Koans, and the "Rails for Zombies" CodeSchool course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official Rails Guides are a great place to learn all things Rails. In this case, there is a [A Guide to the Rails Command Line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate) which spells out the difference. Essentially, a Rails scaffold "is a full set of model, database migration for that model, controller to manipulate it, views to view and manipulate the data, and a test suite for each of the above." `generate`, on the other hand, is used to create models and controllers separately.

The obvious thing I should say here is:  do both and look at the differences. If you're new and you find Rails and/or the command line daunting, play with it and figure it out. Create some new project (`rails new foo`) that you can throw away later. Change into the foo directory, then type `rails generate scaffold Bar`, take note of the files created and what's in those files, then go back to the command line and type `rails destroy scaffold Post`. Then do the same with `rails generate controller` and `rails generate model`. The best way to understand is by experimenting yourself.